# Object Poolers + Colliders + Animator, how do you do it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Just ran into a serious performance problem.

I use object pooler script which loads all assets, sets them to inactive and returns an object from the pool whenever a script asks.

If object goes beyond screen, it is set to inactive and goes back to the pool.

The other script takes an object from the pool, sets its position and activates it. Now the problems:

1) If the object has a collider, it's expensive to move it via transform, but I cannot move it via rigidbody while it is inactive. I was thinking to leave the objects active, but wouldn't that be harsh on resources? How would you go about that?

2) Some objects have spritesheet animation and whenever they get reactived, the animator has to reinitialize and it creates spikes in the profiler. Could you recommend anything?

[Edit] The game was running smoothly until I added these new objects with colliders and animators. Now it's slowing down everytime these objects are activated.

Profiler shows that it's mainly due to these two problems: colliders changed and animation initializing.

Comment: In a past project, I was having similar problems with activating/deactivating objects. I found it was sometimes more performant to disable CPU-heavy components and leave the rest of the object "active" but irrelevant to gameplay. For example, render and animation components don't really need to be turned off if they're frustum culled, but they can be expensive to turn back on, so I'd just leave them running. Same for colliders, after some careful layer management.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll do it this way as well. Good to know I'm not alone.

Comment: are your rigidbody kinematic or not?

Comment: @Revolter: moving a kinematic rigidbody trough transform isn't expensive. It could be slightly inaccurate for what concern collision detection (especially at high speed) but you should be able to use transform when instantiating them from the pool without performance penalties. Btw, why do you need to move it before reactivating it?

Comment: @Heisenbug: Cause in some cases they might be situated on the screen inactive (and invisible). So if I activate them before I move them, they are flashing on the screen. You are right, it isn't that much expensive, but profiler still shows calculation made by collider. It's the animation that gets reinitialized that steals most performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main problems was that object pooler created all objects with colliders in the same place and colliders were going crazy. Don't forget to set up your collision matrix, it definitely decreased the CPU load a lot.